# What's Scotty holding?

Tags: star-trek, video-games

In the game *Star Trek Timelines*, the image of the character Lt Commander Scott is this:

[image]

**What is he holding in this picture?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Apparently it's a Trident scanner

After looking through the various pieces of equipment he needs, I found out that it's a [trident scanner](http://startrektimelineswiki.com/wiki/Trident_Scanner):

[image]

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trident_scanner) says it's used for repairing power relays apparently!

We see Scotty using one in *TOS* 'The Doomsday Machine':

[image]

Comment: In the DS9 epiode where the go back in time to the Tribbel episode of TOS you see a tech wielding one of theses and a short discussion about replacing a relay.